# divergence of $[\hat\epsilon.\vec{E}]$?

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-operator, calculus

What is the identity of divergence of $[\hat\epsilon.\vec{E}]$, where $\hat\epsilon$ is tensor 3x3, and E is vector 1x3

$\nabla.[\hat\epsilon.\vec{E}]=?$

$\nabla.[\phi\vec{E}]=\phi\nabla.\vec{E}+\vec{E}.\nabla\phi  $ for scalar $\phi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product of tensors can be expanded as follow，
$$\hat\epsilon\cdot\vec{E}=\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_{11}\hat x \hat x&\epsilon_{12}\hat x \hat y &\epsilon_{13}\hat x \hat z\\
\epsilon_{21}\hat y \hat x&\epsilon_{22}\hat y \hat y &\epsilon_{23}\hat y \hat z\\
\epsilon_{31}\hat z \hat x&\epsilon_{32}\hat z \hat y &\epsilon_{33}\hat z \hat z \end{pmatrix} 
\cdot \begin{pmatrix} E_1 \hat x\\E_2 \hat y\\E_3 \hat z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
(E_1 \epsilon_{11}+E_2 \epsilon_{12}+E_3 \epsilon_{13} )\hat x\\
(E_1 \epsilon_{21}+E_2 \epsilon_{22}+E_3 \epsilon_{23} ) \hat y\\
(E_1 \epsilon_{31}+E_2 \epsilon_{32}+E_3 \epsilon_{33} ) \hat z\end{pmatrix}
$$
then we can get 
 $$\nabla \cdot [\hat\epsilon \cdot \vec{E}]=\sum_{j=1,2,3} (
\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial x}\epsilon_{1j}+\frac{\partial \epsilon_{1j}}{\partial x}E_j)+\sum_{j=1,2,3} (
\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial y}\epsilon_{2j}+\frac{\partial \epsilon_{2j}}{\partial y}E_j)+\sum_{j=1,2,3} (
\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial z}\epsilon_{3j}+\frac{\partial \epsilon_{3j}}{\partial z}E_j)$$

If $\hat\epsilon$ is not a function of position$(x,y,z)$, then 
$$\frac{\partial \epsilon_{1j}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \epsilon_{2j}}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \epsilon_{3j}}{\partial z}=0 $$
and the expressions can be simplified as $$\nabla \cdot [\hat\epsilon \cdot \vec{E}]=\sum_{j=1,2,3} 
\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial x}\epsilon_{1j}+\sum_{j=1,2,3} 
\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial y}\epsilon_{2j}+\sum_{j=1,2,3}
\frac{\partial E_j}{\partial z}\epsilon_{3j}$$